# Submodule isn't cloned when main repository are cloned

Tags: git

I have a project `main` and small project `small`.
To make `small` as a submodule of `main`, I've done like this:

```
cd main_project
git submodule add git@bitbucket.org:ironsand/small.git small
git add .gitmobules
git commit -m "add submodule small"
git push
```

And in another directory I run `git clone git@bitbucket.org:ironsand/main.git`, but the `small` subdirectory is empty.

This is the first time I use `submodule` function of `git`, so probably I'm doing something wrong. Could you tell me how to clone submodule when main repository is cloned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a clone, do a `recursive` clone for cloning the submodules as well

```
git clone --recursive git@bitbucket.org:ironsand/main.git
```